# Call tuple from outside function as dual variable in another function

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x, tuples

I'm hitting a problem I don't seem to be able to solve in my algorith.

Let's say I have:

```
func1(x)
```

which returns a 2 element tuple, and I also have

```
func2(y,z)
```

which I want to use that tuple on. But everytime I try to call it on function2 as

```
func2(func1)
```

I get the error "missing 1 required positional argument:" because the function is receiving the tuple as:

```
func2((tuple1st_element, tuple2nd_element),)
```

and not

```
func2(tuple1st_element, tuple2nd_element)
```

How can I get it to do the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`*` argument unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
func2(*func1())
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def func1():
...     return 1, 2
...
>>> def func2(a, b):
...     return a + b
...
>>> func2(*func1())
3
>>>
```

Or, in simpler terms, doing this:

```
func(*(1, 2))
```

is equivalent to this:

```
func(1, 2)
```